# Get Data From Table User with Password HashBytes

Tags: laravel, hashbytes

```
 $user=User::where('USERNAME_ACC','=',$username)->where('PASSWORD','=',"HASHBYTES('md5',$password)")->first();
```

I want to get data from Table User with the query

```
 $user=DB::select("select * from AccessUser where USERNAME_ACC='$username' and PASSWORD=HASHBYTES('md5','$password')");
```

if I use this query I can get data from my table

Comment: Can you elaborate? Your question is totally unclear and how are the two queries interconnected?

Comment: When you use laravel you don't need to use md5 , it is bad practice to strore password , instead you can use laravel default Hash facade, 'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword), and  retriving the user you just need to use default Auth facade  if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    // Authentication passed...
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}  once you do it , just retrieve the authenticated user with , $user=Auth::user();  , it wi8ll return the authenticated user

Comment: Make sure the ```User``` and ```AccessUser``` have same model to use **Eloquent**

Comment: As you are not able to use  Eloquent. Share your user model information

Comment: what the error you are getting with  Eloquent